# Invalid json representation of date

Tags: java, json, serialization, date

My code:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;
...
public void testDateSerializer() {
  final Date date = new Date();
  log.info("Today's date: " + date + " and date.getTime()=" + date.getTime());
  final JSONObject jsonObjectForDate = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(date);
  log.info("Same date expressed in json: " + jsonObjectForDate.toString());
}
```

The output:

```
INFO - 2011-08-13 22:12:04,938 - TestJsonConversion.testDateSerializer(52) | Today's date: Sat Aug 13 22:12:04 EDT 2011 and date.getTime()=1313287924927
INFO - 2011-08-13 22:12:05,216 - TestJsonConversion.testDateSerializer(55) | Same date expressed in json: {"date":13,"day":6,"hours":22,"minutes":12,"month":7,"seconds":4,"time":1313287924927,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":111}
```

My questions:

- Why year=111. We are still in 2011 unless I missed something!
- I am on US ETD, so offset is -4 hours, not +240, which, even expressed in minutes is still wrong regarding the sign of the offset.

So what am I doing wrong?  Is this a bug in the library?  If so, what library should I use to accomplish the same conversion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this behavior is completely expected, believe it or not.

You are using the class `java.util.Date`.  This class has mostly a bunch of deprecated methods.  See the documentation here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Now your JSON serializer is just going to make a JSON string out of the getters in your Java object.  Take a look at the getters in the `java.util.Date` class.  Most are deprecated and you can see why.  The year is relative to 1900!  The time zone offset **is** in minutes backwards.

To make your application work the way you would expect, check out the deprecation warnings for `Date` which tell you to use `GregorianCalendar`.  However, I recommend using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  A little learning curve, but this is so worth it.

Answer (score 4):

Joda Time is indeed the way to go.  However, if you are stuck with `java.util.Date` for whatever reason, you could customize the serialization this way:

```
   JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();
   config.registerJsonValueProcessor(
        Class.forName("java.util.Date"), 
        new NiceDateJsonBeanProcessor());
   final JSONObject jsonObjectForDate = JSONSerializer.toJSON(object, jsonConfig)
```

Where `NiceDateJsonBeanProcessor` is how you define what you want your `java.util.Date`
object to be serialized as. In my case, I was happy with unix time, so:

```
public static class NiceDateJsonBeanProcessor implements JsonValueProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object processArrayValue(Object value, JsonConfig jsonConfig) {
        return process(value, jsonConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public Object processObjectValue(String key, Object value, JsonConfig jsonConfig) {
        return process(value, jsonConfig);
    }
    private Object process(Object value, JsonConfig jsonConfig) {
        if (value instanceof java.util.Date) {
            java.util.Date d = (java.util.Date) value;
            return d.getTime();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Joda Time is indeed the way to go." I agree with that in general, but what difference would that make here? Does it help with JSON serialization?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to look at the source of JSONObject [here](http://libjson-java.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.2.3/JSONObject_8java-source.html)

Basically, it treats your passed-in Date object as a Java Bean. So, it iterates through reflection, all the "get*" methods in your date object and that's what you see in your JSONObject.

All the [java.util.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object's get methods are deprecated and you see weirdness, like the year being 111 instead of 2011.

If you want to pass date objects via JSON, you might consider passing them as String objects formatted in a specific way OR use Calendar.

Comment: Thank you. I indeed moved to using String objects to use the format I wanted and get rid of most of the getters.